# how to change the styling of the drop down calendar of the ngx-daterangepicker-material

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to change some of the styling of the calendar like top, left and width. How do I do that?

This here is my date range picker. Adding a class to it and adding style in it does not update the drop down calendar.

```
<div>
    <input type="text"
    ngxDaterangepickerMd
    [(ngModel)]="selected"
    [showCustomRangeLabel]="true"
    [ranges]="ranges"
    [showClearButton]="true"
    [showCancel]="true"
    [maxDate]="maxDate"
    [minDate]="minDate"
    [linkedCalendars]="true"
    (datesUpdated)="datesUpdated($event)"
    readonly/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what you were using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material ?

Comment: @Awais yes thats the one.

Comment: OK then try to just change the styles which effect that less on date picker structure as it create problems if you set custom top left width etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As directive will place the content for the calendar. You can hack those classes which comes with the content. As main div of that content is having a class md-drppicker, you can use this class to update the style in styles.css file.

```
.md-drppicker {
  top:0;
}
```